# Configuring WL to listen for my IP address

Tags: networking, weblogic, port, firewall

I know how to configure WL to listen for a my IP address instead of `localhost`. I had done it in past and it worked as well. Today suddenly things are broken, as usual I started my server configured for listening to my IP address and I was not even able to open the WL console.

I thought it could be some proxy issue so I removed all my proxies and then tried but no help. Then just to be double sure I used `curl` and tried to GET the admin page but still no help.

Then I thought that it could related to some recent firewall blocking rules my company might have pushed so this link and added my port to unblock list for both inbound and unbound rules, but still not help.

Does anyone has any idea whether there is something I can do to debug or rectify this issue. Please note that I have already tried changing my WL listen address to "no address", specific address etc. but it doesn't help, and I have tried `netstat -a -n` command and I can see there is a connection listening for my IP:port, but in the end I cannot access that connection/socket or in other words I cannot access my WL admin console or my application

Comment: It would be great if downvoters can also mention reasons while down-voting.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your servers and applications are running. But you are not able to access them.
In this case, You can start from here.

```
    1. Verify whether you are able to ping the admin host. If so, see whether telnet is allowed on admin port. 
    2. Try accessing the console with both FQDN and ip address.
    3. If vnc server is configured on your server which is hosting weblogic, try launching chrome from VNC to access weblogic admin console.
```

Comment: I have verified and I am able to ping those IP addresses. Since I am not able to open WL console so it also means that I am not able to do telnet as well.